# counts days inbetween then add class to those days with nested divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

ok i have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="test">02/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">03/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">04/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">05/12/2013</div>
    <div class="class1">06/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test"><07/12/2013/div>
    <div class="test">08/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">09/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">10/12/2013</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="test">11/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">12/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">13/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">14/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">15/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">16/12/2013</div>
    <div class="class2">17/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">18/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">19/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">20/12/2013</div>
    <div class="test">21/12/2013</div>
</div>
```

In this case class1 and class2 are added dynamiclly using angularJS so how do i go about counting how many divs with a class of test there are between the two divs class1 class2?

Comment: I'm not sure how your question and title relate to each other.

Comment: sorry maybe I have named it wrong

Comment: Also, how many `div` elements do you think there are between the two? Given they're in different parent elements, I'm not sure how you'd count.

Comment: I've tried clacluating the days inbetween the two divs because the have a date tied to there scope.
I have jquery and angularJS available.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
$(function(){
    var $class1 = $('.class1');
    var $class2 = $('.class2');
    var $afterClass1 = $class1.nextAll('.test');
    var $beforeClass2 = $class2.prevAll('.test');

    var count = $afterClass1.length + $beforeClass2.length;

    $('.count').html(count);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAsty/

**Edit:**
Better visualization
http://jsfiddle.net/SAsty/3/

**Edit 2:**

Do something like:

```
var $allBetween =  $afterClass1.add($beforeClass2);
$allBetween.addClass('between');
```

Comment: yes that is exactly what i mean thanks @jan J answer accepted as soon as it will allow!

Comment: how do i go about pushing a class to the counted divs?

Comment: thank you just checked the last fiddle and it works just as that :D

Comment: ok my problem now arrises if there is an extra column between the two dates..
http://jsfiddle.net/SAsty/4/

Comment: you my sir are a genious!

Comment: I have found just one error with this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SAsty/9/
If the class is on the same row it counts them to the end no matter what...

Comment: as stated above if the class is on the same row it still knocks to the end why?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$divs = $('.row div');
var count = $divs.index($('.class2')) - $divs.index($('.class1')) - 1;
```